# IsHandleCreated Prop. is always false for gridview control in dev express

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

My windows form contains `​DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl` on `Form1` similar way there is also 2nd class called it as `Form2`. On Form1 I am loading data from database. When I double click on grid row it assigns to an Form2. on `Form1` `gridControl1_DoubleClick` event IsHandleCreated prop is true (`Form2` is Inherited from `Form1`)

```
    void gridControl1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gridControl1.IsHandleCreated)
        {
        }
        Form2 obj = new Form2();
        obj.Display();
    }
```

so I have created one property like on Form1

```
    public GridControl GridControl1
    {
        get { return gridControl1; }

    }
```

but when I call the Display() method of Form2 and check the IsHandleCreated prop on Form2 is false.

```
public void Display()
    {
        if (handleCreated)
        {

        }           
    }
```

complete code as below `**Form1**`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public GridControl GridControl1
        {
            get { return gridControl1; }

        }

        public bool handleCreated
        {
            get { return gridControl1.IsHandleCreated; }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            gridControl1.DataSource = CreateTable(20);
            gridControl1.DoubleClick += gridControl1_DoubleClick;

        }

        void gridControl1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (gridControl1.IsHandleCreated)
            {
            }
            Form2 obj = new Form2();
            obj.Display();
        }


        private DataTable CreateTable(int rowCount)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("String", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Int", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(string.Format("Row {0}", i), i, DateTime.Today.AddDays(i));
            }
            return table;
        }
}

**Form2**
public class Form2 : Form1
    {
        public Form2()
        {
        }
        public void Display()
        {
            if (handleCreated)
            {

            }
            //Form1 obj = new Form1();

            //if (obj.handleCreated)
            //{
            //}
        }
    }
```

In Form2 handleCreated its always false I dont know why?
please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `form2` object is just only initialized. Control will get its handle only after window is created, which displays this control. So, you need to call `form2.Show()` or `form2.ShowDialog()` and after that check for `gridControl1.IsHandleCreated`.
You can simply test this behavior by using this code:

```cs
Form2 obj = new Form2();
MessageBox.Show("Created: " + obj.handleCreated);

obj.Show();
MessageBox.Show("Shown: " + obj.handleCreated);
```

Comment: if in case form2 is not a form its a simple class then.

Comment: Then you must put `form2.GridControl1` to form. For example: `Form2 obj = new Form2(); Form form = new Form(); form.Controls.Add(form2.GridControl1); form.Show(); MessageBox.Show("Shown: " + obj.handleCreated);`

Comment: also I want to access Form1 IsHandleCreated prop into Form2

Comment: Add property to `Form2` class: `public Form1 MainForm {get; set;}`, assign it: `Form2 obj = new Form2(); obj.MainForm = this;` and use it in `Form2` object: `MessageBox.Show(MainForm.handleCreated.ToString());`.

Comment: why such thing is happened can you explain and how can i handle this "One possible scenario to get IsHandleCreated to return false in another thread is when your main GUI thread is busy running the code in InitializeComponent()"

Comment: @IMMORTAL No, I have no experience in threading. Try to ask this as a new question in SO.